# iphone app name changed in "release" mode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am getting ready to submit my first app and for some reason when I changed xcode to "release" mode - the name below my icon changes.  The info.plst file still says [Product_name] and when I go into the info section of the app it still says what I want it to say under Product name.  When I switch back to debug and run the app the name is correct again.  What would make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the "bundle display name" option in the info.plist to change your apps name on the devices icon screen.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Active Target settings via the Project/Edit Active Target "Blah" menu item.

Check that the *Configuration* combo box at the the top of the dialog (on the *Build* tab) is set to *All Configurations* when you edit the *Product Name* setting in the *Packaging* settings.